# An app downloaded from the Mac App Store re-installs itself after I delete it. How can I remove it permanently?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, macos, launchpad

The app in question is iCare by Chen Yuhua. I have tried uninstalling the proper way through launchpad and also manually by removing all files and system files that are returned by Searching "iCare" and "Yuhua".

In both cases, the app immediately reappears in the updates tab of the Mac App Store. The developer told me that the problem is with the store, not his app.

So, how can I permanently remove it so that it doesn't reinstall itself?

Answer (score 1):

Some troubleshooting tips:

1. Open the Mac App store and choose the menu Store > Sign Out
2. Log out of your account (save work and then choose the menu Apple > Log Out ...
3. Log in and hold the shift (this prevents apps from automatically starting. If you miss the timing, just continue - things will be slower as a result)
4. Disconnect any network cables and turn off WiFi
5. Restart your Mac (Apple Menu > Restart)

At this point, you've disabled the checks and tools the app store will use to try and continue a download.

Open Launchpad and delete any copies of that app (and any others you wish to clean up).

Once that's done, restart your Mac.

1. Reconnect WiFi and network
2. Open the Mac App Store
3. Sign in again
4. Check for Unfinished Downloads (under the Sign in option)

At that point, you should be save from further intrusion of the App Store.

There's some great information on the tools here:

- [App Store repeatedly asking me to update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129788/app-store-repeatedly-asking-me-to-update)

Comment: Followed your instructions to the letter, but on checking the updates tab in the app store... [Recurring app annoyance](http://i.imgur.com/CDrvBcp.png) apparently it didn't work.

Comment: @NPattison bummer - I've un-stuck quite a few with that procedure. I don't have other options other than calling Apple Support to verify they don't have some new ideas or things to try. Perhaps they can see something on the server end to clue them into the block.

Comment: much appreciated all the same!
The link you provided has let me switch off the app store updates entirely so at least I can prevent the app reappearing that way.